# How to split spacing and | in java

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I'm having trouble splitting both at once right now as I am trying to split the code below

> RCMP|Colour Demon|Magenta Boxer
>
> NUPI|Number Picker|Random Numburrs
>
> QUFI|Quick Fingers|Digitology

and here is my method that involves it. It worked for the others but because this one has spacing I am now having trouble

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    str = input.nextLine();

    temp = str.split("\\s|\\|")

    System.out.println(temp[0]) // should print RCMP


    // Array out of bounds error
    System.out.println(temp[1]) // should print COLOUR

    Game game = new Game(temp[0],(temp[1]+temp[2]),(temp[3] + temp[4]))
}
```

the intended output that I want is something like this or better

> RCMP- temp[0]
>
> Colour - temp[1]
>
> Demon - temp[2]
>
> Magenta - temp[3]
>
> Boxer - temp[4]

It is so I can store them into the game

When i attempt to print temp[1] which should be Colour it gives an array out of bounds error instead

Comment: the code didn't split properly but it is actually \\| and \\s+ but it still doesn't print the way I wanted to

Comment: What's the intended output of temp 0,1, etc...?

Comment: And what is the current print?

Comment: the intended output is something like this

CODE


Colour 


Demon


Magenta 

Boxer

Right now i have an array out of bounds error when i try to print temp[1]

Comment: All elements of temp array should have only one word?

Comment: Use [edit] option to add more informations to your question. Don't post them only in comments (not everyone who will be able to answer your question reads them).

Comment: Also it looks like you want to split on `|` so what is wrong with `split("\\|")`?

Comment: i updated it. yes only one word

Comment: What is type of `input`? If it is Scanner then `input.next();` will not include spaces in returned value since they are considered as delimiter. Maybe you should use `nextLine()` instead. Anyway consider updating your code example with more details which will let us actually reproduce your problem. Without it we can only guess what you want to achieve and what is not working for you.

Comment: Yea I gave the wrong one. Is RCMP not CODE but the result is still the same

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
scan.nextLine()
```

To get the string

And split using regex:

```
yourString.split("\\s|\\|");
```

for example the line: `RCMP|Colour Demon|Magenta Boxer` would make:

```
{"RCMP", "Colour", "Demon", "Magenta", "Boxer"}
```

Comment: I split it just now and when i try to print temp[1] which should be Colour it gave me an array out of bounds error instead

Comment: @user1879973 make sure you are using your whole line for `yourString` `input.nextLine();` not `input.next()` (returns a word.)

Comment: @user1879973 Show us your actual code, actual data, and describe output you want to get from it explaining logic behind this output. For now I'm starting to suspect that you may want to simply set Scanners delimiter to `[\\s|]+` and simply use `while(input.hasNext()){ String token = input.next();}`

Comment: Is the data a text file?

Comment: yeah must be [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -_- I better delete my answer

Comment: the data is a pure text file.

Comment: @user1879973 then in the while loop do: str = input.nextLine() and then do my answer